# MySQL autoincrement column have diffrent behaviour with different databases

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I have one working project in php and mysql.
In which I am using one column syntax for all my auto increment columns like below -

```
  CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sometext` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

And for inserting records in this table in my whole proect I am using below syntax -

```
   INSERT INTO mytable(ID,sometext)
VALUES(0,'Sometext')
```

And this is working fine.

But when I copied same DB and project and this code stopped working
So I changed my insert with below

```
 INSERT INTO mytable( sometext)
VALUES( 'Sometext')
```

But this is very weird... In previous project old syntax is working fine but for new I have to make code change in 100 of places.
Can somebody tell me whats wrong with new MYSQL DB that it stopped supporting old syntax.

Comment: Your "old syntax" is incorrect. It had worked only due to disabled `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` SQL mode. You should use compatible syntax while it is possible - either `INSERT INTO mytable(sometext) VALUES('Sometext')` or `INSERT INTO mytable(ID, sometext) VALUES(NULL, 'Sometext')`.

Comment: After reading it I ran 
`SELECT @@sql_mode` and it returned same for both of my databases - 
`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and still things working differently.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is probably that your new database servers has the configuration option `sql_mode=NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`. Therefore only a NULL will cause an auto-increment to be generated.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html for full explanation of how sql modes affect your database server.

To avoid having to make code changes, you can change the server option.